# Entity Framework Enum in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I have an enum in the Domain Model:

```
public enum MessageType
{
    Ad = 1,
    Ask = 2
}
```

And I use DTO to transport data from Service Layer to UI Layer.

In the Controller I need to get all messages of a certain type from Service Layer:

```
_messageService.GetAllAds(MessageType.Ad);
```

As the Domain Model is not mapped in the UI, how can I pass it to the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in a project of mine a while back. I ended up copying the enum into the UI layer and having basically two (almost) identical enums (with slightly different names to differentiate them). Essentially, it's like a view model for the enum.

It is not a great solution, and I might refactor my project later if I come up with something better, but it works. One benefit of this is that you can decorate your UI layer enum with UI-relevant attributes that simply wouldn't make sense in the domain layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make something in common available between your Controller and the service.. whether that is the `MessageType` enum you are currently using or some other thing.. maybe you want to pass a `string` in there, but I wouldn't recommend it. Personally I also prefer not to let any domain entities be directly accessible from the controllers (I use view models instead), but for enums, I make an exception.

My advice: allow the controller to still use that enum.